# Log only user name in apache logs

Tags: apache, http-headers

I would like to log only username in apache log. I am using %{Authorization}i in LOGFORMAT but it logs username:password in base64.
due to security reason I have to remove password part, is it possible to do so ?
or at least can I log only first 10 char of the Authorization headers?

Thanks for helping me here.

Comment: `%u` is not good enough?

Comment: it doesn't log anything but just a space

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might find part of the answer in the comments, I want to give you a complete answer as some people may not know how to configure that properly. To only record the username in your Apache log, use this code in your Apache settings:

```
LogFormat "%u" auth_log
CustomLog /var/www/html/composer/auth_log.log auth_log
```

Just keep in mind, the %u code captures the username only if the request is authenticated with HTTP Basic or Digest authentication. If the request isn't authenticated that way, the log entry will show "-".